# How create a CNAME mapping in Amazon Route 53 for custom endpoint elasticsearch in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, cname, opensearch

To make the custom endpoint work. On route 53 , I alias for which resource in aws? And what kind of route.And if I use CNAME do I have to use subdomain?

"After you enable a custom endpoint for your OpenSearch Service domain, you must create a CNAME mapping in Amazon Route 53 (or your preferred DNS service provider) to route traffic to the custom endpoint and its subdomains. Create the CNAME from the custom endpoint (the name of the record) to the auto-generated endpoint (the value of the record). Without this mapping, your custom endpoint won't work. For steps to create this mapping in Route 53, see Configuring DNS routing for a new domain and Creating a hosted zone for a subdomain. For other providers, consult their documentation." [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/customendpoint.html)

[image]

Comment: In the text you have cited, it literally says: for steps to create this mapping in Route53 see...If you actually use R53, this link should give you the basics you need: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-creating.html

Comment: But what address will the CNAME record point to? Custom Endpoint or endpoint? is alias?

Comment: "Create the CNAME from the custom endpoint (the name of the record) to the auto-generated endpoint (the value of the record)" - so it's need to be something.com.br CNAME to search.******************************.amazonaws.com

Comment: i did it and it didn't work,  g----.-----.com.br CNAME Simple - 
search-g-----.amazonaws.com

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly didn't work?

Comment: Work!! forget it kkk thank you! ^^'

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This works for me.

I create CNAME with the same name of custom endpoint and point to auto-generated endpoint.

[image]